# Azure DevOps Pipelines: deploy same artifacts in UAT to Production with a manual trigger

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My requirement is to promote the same artifacts from UAT to Production.

My release to UAT is manual, whereas my release to Production is triggered when UAT completes.

The release to UAT and Production have approvers. My issue is that, after release to UAT completes, the approver automatically gets an email to approve release to Production. This confuses the approver, because testing in UAT takes a few days and I don't want to send them an email for Production immediately.

So my question is - is there is a way to promote the very same artifacts in UAT to Production with a manual trigger for Production?

Comment: Would you please mark your answer? This will make it easier for people who have the same question to find answers.

Comment: Do you understand that I have to wait for a few hours to mark my own answer, Quian?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding a post-deployment approval to the UAT environment, as a signal that UAT tests passed properly.